# JQuery: Using data attribute to affix a function

Tags: jquery

Quick Question

I notice this in bootstrap that it was manage to use the right function by using the data attribute. Like in dropdowns, you can use data-toggle to initiate it. I would like to know how this works. This might save me time to declare each of them in .ready or .load

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It works absolutely the same as any other selector (the code from bootstrap modal):

```
$('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function ( e ) {
    // show modal
});
```

This bind means: for all elements under `body` that fit `[data-toggle="modal"]` selector handle the `click` event by specified callback function

Comment: if the name of my toggle is not modal, does the fomrat for the event changes? like click.myfunc.data-api ? Also, should I put this on my .ready?

Comment: @Mr A: `[data-toggle="modal"]` -- this is a generic selector, means "all elements that have parameter `data-toggle` equal to `modal`". So you can use everything as a parameter name and everything for parameter value

Comment: `click.modal.data-api` - is just a `click` event

Comment: Yep, you need to put it in `$(function() {});`

Comment: Can I just go with a click event and or should I be specific with click.modal.data-api?

Comment: @Mr A: it is a regular `click` with namespace http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names So `click.foo` and `click` and `click.bar.baz` will be triggered on just click

Comment: oh. so .foo is like a class in CSS? But this doesn't mean that I have to have a class .foo just to have this event clicked?

Comment: @Mr A: yep, it is just a convenient way of grouping event handlers so you can `.off()` bunch of them in one call